# Error Installing Sitecore Commerce 9

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, powershell

I am getting the cast error while installing the Sitecore commerce 9.

**Error:**

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to
>   the type 'System.String' required by parameter
>   'SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath'. Specified method is not supported.
>   At
>   C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.2.14\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:80
>   char:32
>   +     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params
>   +                                   ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-SitecoreConfiguration], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

Comment: Welcome to SSE community Sai Raj. Can you make sure the path you provided in 'SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath' is pointing to a specific file, else you can also pass folder name with the version number rather using the wildcard.

Comment: I would recommend setting this attribute in your ps1 script like this: `SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.*"` . Change ..\ accordingly to your location. Also check whether you have folder together with zip file with same name. if so delete one of them. This error is usually caused by this as powershell thinks there are two objects with same name...

Comment: Thanks, AmitabhVyas, PeterProchazka,
The Solution worked fine for me.
 Changed value 
SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.*"
to
SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.2.19"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had run into similar issue. Check the path value for the parameter SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath and then check the version you have for the zip file.
And then change the wildcard to full path to the zip file to resolve. 
[image: Path as in the Installation script]

[image: The file name]